# CUDA-enabled graphics processor as VMware?

Tags: cuda

I'm taking a course that teaches CUDA. I would like to use it my personal laptop, but I don't have Nvidia graphics processor. mine is ATI . so I was thinking is there any Virtual Hardware simulator that I can use? or that there is no other way than using a PC with CUDA Graphics processor.

Thank you very much

Comment: You could use Amazon EC2 - on-demand pricing for their cg1.4xlarge instance type (two Tesla M2050 GPUs) is $2.10.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The CUDA toolkit used to ship with a host CPU emulation mode, but that was deprecated early in the 3.0 release cycle and has been fully removed from toolkits for the best part of two years.

Your only real option today is to use [Ocelot](http://code.google.com/p/gpuocelot/). It has a PTX assembly translator and a pretty reliable reimplementation of the CUDA runtime for x86 CPUs, and there is also a rather experimental PTX to AMD IL translator (I have no experience with the latter). On a modern linux system with an up to date GNU toolchain, Ocelot is reasonably easy to get running. I am not sure if there is a functioning Windows port or not.

Comment: There is also CUDA x86, a commercial product from The Portland Group.

Answer (score -1):

CUDA has its own emulation mode witch runs everything on CPU. Problem is that in such case you don't have real concurrency so programs that runs successfully in emulation mode can fail (and usually does) in normal mode. You can develop your code in emulation mode, but then you have to debug it on computer with CUDA card.

Comment: CUDA *had* its own emulation mode. It was deprecated and remove a long time ago....